# Angular 5 router read encrypt params

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In Angular 5, I have a route config like this:

```
{path: 'checkout/success/:type/:bookingId', component: SuccessComponent}
```

Then when I read this url:

```
http://localhost:9001/checkout/success/airport-bus/Mdi7D-2mNb_qeDIw8gWGJw==?vnp_Amount=4000000&vnp_BankCode=NCB&vnp_BankTranNo=20180129102837&vnp_CardType=ATM&vnp_OrderInfo=1801290998&vnp_PayDate=20180129103116&vnp_ResponseCode=00&vnp_TmnCode=DULICH01&vnp_TransactionNo=13010138&vnp_TxnRef=18012945505&vnp_SecureHashType=MD5&vnp_SecureHash=8c9d820c7ef973fcd999de7322986072
```

Angualr auto cut the param for bookingId, it redirect to:

```
http://localhost:9001/checkout/success/airport-bus/Mdi7D-2mNb_qeDIw8gWGJwcode
```

And then boongkingId = Mdi7D-2mNb_qeDIw8gWGJwcode (Too short)
I can not get full the bookingId needed.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I checked the issue. if the url is having == then url gets truncated after that. trying to check for the reason

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `==` in your `:bookingId` (Mdi7D-2mNb_qeDIw8gWGJw==?....). If you omit those, Angular 4 should not cut the rest of the url.

You can only use certain characters in your parameters, have a look at the specification in [IETF RFC 398](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for more details.

**EDIT** added explanation from IETF RFC 3986 about params

From the explanation found in [IETF RFC 3986, section 3.3.  Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic syntax.  URI producing applications
> often use the reserved characters allowed in a segment to delimit
> scheme-specific or dereference-handler-specific subcomponents.  For
> example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.